# How can I load multiple stl files with array variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, stl, three.js

```
    var stlpath = '../assets/models/stl/part';
    var stlformat = '.stl';
    var part = new Array();

    for( var i = 1; i<28; i++){

        var url = stlpath + i + stlformat;

        stlloader.load(url, function (geometry) {
            console.log(geometry);

            var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xffffff} );

            part = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);
            part.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI; part.rotation.z = -0.5 * Math.PI;
            part.position.set(0, -15, 0);
            part.scale.set(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
            part.castShadow = true;
            part.receiveShadow = true;

            scene.add(part);
        });
    }
```

I have loaded multiple stl files successfully with this code. But this code hold stl files with just one variable, "part", so I am not able to handle each of stl files. I want adjust each stl with separated variables.

I tried to use an array as a variable.

```
    var stlpath = '../assets/models/stl/part';
    var stlformat = '.stl';
    var part = new Array();

    for( var i = 1; i<28; i++){

        var url = stlpath + i + stlformat;

        stlloader.load(url, function (geometry) {
            console.log(geometry);

            var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xffffff} );

            part[i] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);
            part[i].rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI; part.rotation.z = -0.5 * Math.PI;
            part[i].position.set(0, -15, 0);
            part[i].scale.set(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
            part[i].castShadow = true;
            part[i].receiveShadow = true;

            scene.add(part[i]);
        });
    }
```

But this code doesn't work without any error message. I have no idea that why it doesn't work. Can you give any advice, solution, or example?

Thank you

Comment: what happens when you put the following declaration inside the for-loop `var part = new Array();`

Comment: Nothing happened. Same as before.

Comment: What is "the error" it is outputting? The second code you posted won't work as you expect because you are trying to use the loop index within an async callback.